# Parse Apache combined log format timestamps with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have an Apache log file containing timestamps like this:

`[26/Aug/2016:17:56:57 GMT Summer Time]`

which I want to parse in C#.

So far I have the following:

`DateTime.ParseExact(logtime, "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

This handles the date/time part but not the timezone, but I can't find a format specifier that will parse the "GMT Summer Time" part. Any ideas?

Comment: Are they always GMT based or can there be other base TZs used?

Comment: Some log lines include the actual TZ offset, like [31/Aug/2016:10:35:43 -0700]. These numeric ones should be easy to deal with, its finding a general solution that will handle 'GMT Summer Time' i'm struggling with.

Comment: There is a way to correlate a timezone name to an offset, but that is not a valid name: in NET it is called `GMT Daylight` but I think there is no offset for it.  You could accumulate your own dictionary of texts and related offsets then swap them out.